# One Slower/Larger VS Two Faster/Smaller RAM

Tags: performance, memory, performance-tuning

Generally speaking, performance-wise, which one is the best (putting brands aside)?

**1x 8GB 1333MHz RAM**

or

**2x 4GB 2400MHz RAM**

Both DDR3.

Comment: Define performance? Database? Calcculationn monster? It totally depends - 2x4gb is faster in ram bandwidth, but whether that matters....

Answer (score 1):

Generally 2x4GB because your theoretical maximum memory bandwidth will be doubled with dual channel access.  Also you need to make sure that you use the correct pair of slots on your motherboard.